# Why JSF checkBox inputs new value to map

Tags: jsf, checkbox, hashmap, el

I have a `checkBox` inside dataTable in my `JSF` page with value, which it gets from map which is in bean.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="rowChecked"
    value="#{messagesListBean.selectedRowIndexesMap[rowIndex]}">
        <a4j:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="@none"
            limitRender="true"
            listener="#{messagesListBean.rowChecked(rowIndex, rec)}">
        </a4j:ajax>
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:outputLabel for="rowChecked" class="checkbox-style" />
```

Map is initialized when page loads and it initializes just fine - has 4 values, all of them are false. Map itself looks like this:

```
public Map<Integer, Boolean> selectedRowIndexesMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

The problem is when I press one of the `checkBoxes`. It should edit value inside the map according to `rowNumber`. What it does is it add completely new element to the map, it does not edit it.

For example, if before clicking `checkbox` map looked like this: *0-false; 1-false; 2-false; 3-false;*

After clicking the `checkbox`, it looks like this: *0-true; 0-false; 1-false; 2-false; 3-false;*

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because numbers in EL are by default evaluated as `Long`. I.e. `#{rowIndex}` is actually `Long`.

A `Long` value of `0L` does not equal an `Integer` value of `0`. Evidence is below:

```
Long zeroL = 0L;
Integer zero = 0;
System.out.println(zeroL.equals(zero)); // false
```

So it simply inserts a new map entry with `0L` as key instead of replacing the value associated with key of `0`. Change it to a `Map<Long, Boolean>` and it'll work. This problem is unrelated to JSF checkbox.

Comment: You deserve a cookie. Thank you!